# SQL query evaluates COUNT(*) differently if tables are defined as MyISAM or InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am running a **MySQL** database.

I have the following script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `org_apiinteg_assets`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `assessmentinstances`;

CREATE TABLE `org_apiinteg_assets` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `instance_id` varchar(20) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE= MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=1;

CREATE TABLE `assessmentinstances` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `title` varchar(180) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE= MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=1;


INSERT INTO assessmentinstances(id, title) VALUES ('14026lvplotw6','One radio question survey');
INSERT INTO org_apiinteg_assets(id, instance_id) VALUES ('8kp9wgx43jflrgjfe','14026lvplotw6');
```

Looks like this

```
assessmentinstances
+---------------+---------------------------+
|        id     |          title            |
+---------------+---------------------------+
| 14026lvplotw6 | One radio question survey |
+---------------+---------------------------+

org_apiinteg_assets
+-------------------+---------------+
|        id         |  instance_id  |
+-------------------+---------------+
| 8kp9wgx43jflrgjfe | 14026lvplotw6 |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

And I then have the following query (I reduced it to the simplest failing query)

```
SELECT ai.id, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM assessmentinstances ai, org_apiinteg_assets a 
WHERE a.instance_id = ai.id 
AND ai.id = '14026lvplotw6'
AND a.id != '8kp9wgx43jflrgjfe';
```

When I run the query I get this

```
null, 0
```

Until now, all is good. Now, here is my issue, when I recreate both tables with `ENGINE=InnoDB` instead of `ENGINE=MyISAM` and run the same query again, I get this:

```
'14026lvplotw6','0'
```

So 2 things are confusing me:

- Why don't I get the same result?
- How can the `COUNT(*)` return 0 in the second case when it actually returns values for the row, and should therefore be 1?

I am lost, I'd appreciate if anybody could explain this behaviour to me.

**EDIT**:
Interestingly, if I add `GROUP BY ai.id` at the end of the query, it works fine in both cases and return no rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen because you are using aggregation function without `GROUP BY`  .. in this case the result for non aggregated column is unpredictable  .. (typically is show the first value encountered  during the query)

Try adding a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT ai.id, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM assessmentinstances ai, org_apiinteg_assets a 
WHERE a.instance_id = ai.id 
AND a.id != '8kp9wgx43jflrgjfe'
AND ai.id = '14026lvplotw6' 
GROUP BY  ai.id;
```

Remember that the use of aggregation in presence of column not mentioned  in group by is deprecated  in SQL and is not allowed in most of the db and in the more recent version of mysql (starting from 5.7)

Comment: I think you are correct, while you were writing your answer I added an EDIT saying that it worked correctly with the `GROUP BY`. So aggregation functions evaluation works differently on the 2 ENGINEs ?

Comment: OK  .. many thanks  .. upvoted .. for your (right) autonomous test

Answer (score 1):

`EXPLAIN SELECT` for MyISAM returns: `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables`. So MyISAM isn't processing any data at all.

For the InnoDB there are two rows of `EXPLAIN` results: one `Using Index` and one `Using where`. So InnoDB data is being scanned and bits of it slip into the output as there is no aggregate function specified for the first column and AFAIK its not specified what should happen in such situation. If you directly specify some aggregate function, then [if there are no matching rows, it will return NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html). So, for example, `SELECT min(ai.id), COUNT(*) ...` would return `NULL, 0`.

Comment: Ho thanks, that is very interesting, I didn't know this EXPLAIN keyword!